# For any $x, x' \in \mathbb{R}^n$ of dimension $n > 0$, if for any $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ of dimension $n > 0$ one has $x . y = x' . y$, then $x = x'$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Since $x \cdot y = x' \cdot y$,
$x_1y_1 + x_2y_2 + x_3y_3 = x_1'y_1 + x_2'y_2 + x_3'y_3$.

I'm not sure how to go from here.
Thank you.

I'm also curious about the variation $x \times y = x' \times y$, then $x = x'$, but in the  $x, x' \in \mathbb{R}^3$ .

Comment: Are you working in $\mathbb R^n$ or $\mathbb R^3$. Note : use  \cdot for $\cdot$ and \times for $\times$

Comment: @Digitallis Hi sorry I've just edited the post again. I'm working in $x, x' \in \mathbb{R}^n$  in dot product while .in $x, x' \in \mathbb{R}^3$  for the cross product

Answer (score 1):

Consider $y= e_1$. What does $xe_1 = x'e_1$ tell you in that case? Can you conclude $x = x'$ from that?

As for the dot product, what if $x' = \lambda x, y = \mu x$ for some nonzero $\lambda, \mu$?